# xpath for a table using multiple nodes and conditions

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, nodes

I have a table and I want to find the xpath for a button that has multiple nodes to make the difference between rest of buttons
Here is the xpath

```
  <div id="widget-results-tabs" class="">
      <ul class="widget-results-list">
          <li class="widget-results-list-item">
          <li class="widget-results-list-item active">
              <span class="active" data-action="widgetResults">Spania</span>
              <ul class="widget-results-list">
                   <li class="widget-results-list-item">
                   <li class="widget-results-list-item active">
                       <span class="active" data-action="widgetResults">Clasament</span>
                       <ul class="widget-results-list widget-results-list-dropdown">
                  </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="widget-results-list-item">
         <li class="widget-results-list-item">
         <li class="widget-results-list-item">
         <li class="widget-results-list-item">
         <li class="widget-results-list-item">
         <li class="widget-results-list-item">
      </ul>
 </div>
```

I want to find the xpath for "Clasament" from "Spania"
I've tried something like this

```
  //ul/li/span[contains(.,'Spania')]/li/span[contains(.,'Clasament')]
```

but it doesn't work...
Can you help me with the right xpath that will contains the condition "Spania" and condition "Clasament" ?

Comment: Your HTML code sample is broken. Update with correct one

Comment: Could you please take a look now at the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below XPath to match required `li` node:

```
//li[./span='Spania']//li[./span='Clasament']
```

Comment: I am receiving 1 result,which is good
But I want to find the "Clasament" button from "Spania"
Your xpath finds the 'Spania" button

Comment: This one `//li[./span='Spania']//li[span='Clasament']`?

Comment: Can you explain me how did you know the answer?or give me some documentation please

Comment: You can check [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_tutorial.pdf)